# Some functions and code not invoked in initialize method in JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, java-20, javafx-19

I tried to build a JavaFX application. In the controller some function in initialize method is not invoked.

For example:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
    txt_name.requestFocus();
    btn_update.setVisible(false);
    btn_delete.setVisible(false);
    chk_active.setSelected(true);
    clear();
    listner_txtbx();
    setTable();
    Populate_Table();
}
```

In the above code, CheckBox selection code and Populate_table method are not invoked and all other methods and codes are invoked.

This is the controller file

```java
public class BrandController implements Initializable {
    public TextField txt_id;
    public TextField txt_name;
    public TextField txt_remarks;
    public Button btn_save;
    public Button btn_update;
    public Button btn_delete;
    public Button btn_clear;
    public CheckBox chk_active;
    public TableView tbl_brand;
    public TableColumn col_slno;
    public TableColumn col_id;
    public TableColumn col_name;
    public TableColumn col_remarks;
    public TableColumn col_status;
    public Button btn_Close;
    private Stage stage_brand;
    ObservableList<obj_Brand> tblData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    DBMysql db = new DBMysql();

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        txt_name.requestFocus();
        btn_update.setVisible(false);
        btn_delete.setVisible(false);
        chk_active.setSelected(true);
        clear();
        listner_txtbx();
        setTable();
        Populate_Table();
    }

    private void clear(){
        txt_name.clear();
        txt_remarks.clear();
        setCode();
        txt_name.requestFocus();

    }

    private void Populate_Table(){
        System.out.println("inside table");
        tblData.clear();
        int status;
        if(chk_active.isSelected()){status=1;}else{status=0;}
        try {
            Statement st = db.con.createStatement();
            System.out.println("select * from " + db.schema + ".tbl_brand where status =" +status+ "");
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from " + db.schema + ".tbl_brand where status =" +status+ "");
            while (rs.next()) {
                tblData.add(new obj_BrandBuilder().setCode(rs.getString("code")).setName(rs.getString("name")).setRemarks(rs.getString("remarks")).setStatus(rs.getString("status")).createObj_Brand());
            }
            st.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(BrandController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

I tried the Populate_Table method using a Button On Action method and the code is working, but it's not invoked in the initialize method.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What do you think `chk_active.isSelected()` is going to do?

Comment: Off-topic: please use proper naming conventions when posting code on a public site

Comment: @James_D - it's a mistake and I correct that mistake to `chk_active.setSelected(true)`  .

Comment: Note that [`initialize()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/Initializable.html) is invoked _after_ the controller has been processed, but _before_  the `load()` method returns. Some updates may need to be scheduled for later processing on the JavaFX Application Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preface**

Put system.outs in you method and check If they really are not executed. I think they are executed.

**Solution**

Initialize is called after the controller creation is finished. Your Scene is not displayed yet.

Put your code in `Platform.runLater()`, this will put the execution in the future.

If this does not work, set the size of the stage to "+1" and after that again to "-1" (for width and height). This triggers the renderer.

If this does not work again, post a working  minimal example of your code.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer @David Weber